# store the output of 1st command in a variable and if a variable is null, run 2nd command

Tags: variables, port

**netstat -na | find "49152" > D:\abc.txt**  stores the output in .txt if the port is running & no OP if port (here 49152) stops running.

There is a specific command to start a port.

My task is to detect if port is down and to start it whenever I run a batch file.

for this, my logic: I want to store the output of above command in a variable and if a variable is null, mentioned command to start the port should be executed. please Help.